# Variables in print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print the variable and their value both in the below code

```
New_veh = "C:\new_buy\Jan"
Used_veh = "C:\usedBuy\Jan"
if(Type=='N'):
    Model = New_veh
elif(Type=='U'):
    Model = Used_veh

....

print(Model, "Analysis File is used for Model building :", Model)
```

Output :

> C:\new_buy\Jan Analysis File is used for Model building :C:\new_buy\Jan

In the above code Model variable resolved to the path variable New_veh or Used_veh based on the condition at both places in print statement.

Is there any way it will resolve at one place only. I'm trying to achieve results like this

> New_veh Analysis File is used for Model building :C:\new_buy\Jan

Here it resolved to path at end but in start it print as it is.

Any help on this ?

Comment: you need an additional var to store "New_veh" or "Used_veh" or to save the name of the var then to use eval to get ts value

Comment: Yes I'm currently doing it by storing it in different var just curious is there any better approach or any function for doing the same

Comment: Note, using single backslash for path on Windows will create problems. Use raw string, escape the backslash or use forward slash. In this case `\n` will cause error.

Comment: As to your question - use a data structure like `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning use `==` rather than `=` to compare

in Python before 3 :

First way :

```
New_veh = "C:\new_buy\Jan"
Used_veh = "C:\usedBuy\Jan"
Model = None
V=None

if(Type=='N'):
    Model = New_veh
    V = "New_veh"
elif(Type=='U'):
    Model = Used_veh
    V = "Used_veh"

print(V, "Analysis File is used for Model building :", Model)
```

Second way :

```
New_veh = "C:\new_buy\Jan"
Used_veh = "C:\usedBuy\Jan"
Model = None

if(Type=='N'):
    Model = "New_veh"
elif(Type=='U'):
    Model = "Used_veh"

print(Model, "Analysis File is used for Model building :", eval(Model))
```

---

In python 3 (`\\` rather than `\`)

First way

```
New_veh = "C:\\new_buy\\Jan"
Used_veh = "C:\\usedBuy\\Jan"
Model = None
V=None

if(Type=='N'):
    Model = New_veh
    V = "New_veh"
elif(Type=='U'):
    Model = Used_veh
    V = "Used_veh"

print(V, "Analysis File is used for Model building :", Model)
```

Second way :

```
New_veh = "C:\\new_buy\\Jan"
Used_veh = "C:\\usedBuy\\Jan"
Model = None

if(Type=='N'):
    Model = "New_veh"
elif(Type=='U'):
    Model = "Used_veh"

print(Model, "Analysis File is used for Model building :", eval(Model))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a data structure like dict

```
models = {'N':('New_veh', r"C:\new_buy\Jan"), 'U':('Used_veh', r'C:\usedBuy\Jan')}
name, model = models[model_type] # model_type=='N' or model_type='U'
print(f'{name}, Analysis File is used for Model building : {model}')
```

Also check Ned Batchelder's [Keep data out of your variable names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

If you like you can go fancy with `namedtuple`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not if this will help you, but based on your expected results this can help you:

```
Type = 'N'
New_veh = 'C:\\new_buy\\Jan'
Used_veh = 'C:\\usedBuy\\Jan'
Model = None
if Type == 'N':
    Model = {
        'model': New_veh,
        'variable': f'{New_veh=}'.split('=')[0]
    }
elif Type == 'U':
    Model = {
        'model': Used_veh,
        'variable': f'{Used_veh=}'.split('=')[0]
    }

print(Model.get('variable'), "Analysis File is used for Model building :", Model.get('model'))
```

This is for version 3.9